# WPF DataGrid scrolling perfomance is slow

Tags: wpf, performance, scroll, datagrid

I'm working on wpf application, which has only one - MainWindow.xaml
and I'm using dataGrid to show my data which are loading from database.

When my dataGrid fill with data for first time i.e on Windows_Load it's pretty slow to scroll down/up, until I reach top/bottom (cross all data [items from database] ), than I can scroll fast and smooth, but problem is
my grid is refreshing every 60 seconds so every 60 seconds I'm scrolling slow and slow ..

```
<DataGrid  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
           BorderBrush="#83D744" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"   RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

as you can see guys, I tried `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` and also I tried setting `EnableRowVirtualization` to False, but even that did not help me much, so I don't know what to do to increase scrolling speed of my `datagrid` when it's filled with data. Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: you should try Paggination and use it with endless style.
Like this you will only load some part of your data. Only the visible rows are loaded :) 
Is think this will lead you to a better ressources (memory etc...) control :)

Comment: Your question is not fully clear. But try this : Set `Width = 400`, `Height = 400`, and remove this `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` .

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, I might try that bro, but what about different sizes of monitors? Will that affect how my data is present .. ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Try this first and let me know.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, that is true mate, when I set Width and Height of my DataGrid, scrolling is way faster. And next is? :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf